# Is it proper to use math-mode inside of table cells?

Tags: tables, math-mode

When making a table, should number values inside of table cells be entered in the math environment? Or is that unnecessary?

Comment: math mode, but usually (or at least often) you do not need to add the `$` markup in each cell use a numeric column type from the dcolumn or siunitx packages, so that the numbers are aligned correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes they should. Please compare:

```
\begin{tabular}{cc}
-1 & 1,02 \\ % bad
$-1$ & $1,02$ % good
\end{tabular}
```

(In some languages comma is a decimal separator).

Comment: So the comma in your good doesn't matter?

Comment: If the comma is supposed to denote the decimal separator, it's a good idea to encase it in curly braces, lest TeX (mis)interpret it as a punctuation character.

Comment: Or better, if you are using a language that use comma as decimal separator, like Spanish, be sure that you have  the correct preamble (`\usepackage[spanish]{babel}` o whatever) and just use `$1.2$`.